# Why is the Lax-Jacobi identity useful in integrability?

Tags: commutator, lie-algebra, poisson-brackets, integrable-systems, intuition

I'm studying integrabilty and there is the so-called Lax-Jacobi identity, which is an implication of the classical Jacobi identity of the Poisson brackets of the Lax-Poisson structure:

$$Cycl_{123} [T_1, \; [\![R,R]\!]_{123} + \{T_2,R_{13}\}-\{T_3,R_{12}\}]=0,$$
where
$$[\![X,Y]\!]_{123}:=[Y_{12},Y_{13}]+[Y_{12},X_{23}]+[X_{32},Y_{13}].$$

I would like some help to get some intuition on this equation or why it is useful in integrability.

Screenshot of my lecture notes:

[image]

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): Consider to double-check the equations for typos.

Comment: No typos, that's what's written in my notes and my lecture notes.

Comment: The first term in the bracket (2.42) does not depend on $X$?? Consider to check footnotes/references 9 & 10.

Comment: I will. Still, coming back to the original question: why is this identity important?